# How to use mixin with 2 parametrs in URL in LESS?

Tags: html, css, less, mixins, preprocessor

How to use mixin with 2 parametrs in URL in LESS?

This code doesn't work:

```
.pic_url(@folder;@name) {
    background-image: url("/@{folder}/@{name}.png");
}
.span {
    .pic_url(F1;N1);
}
```

I have to get this output CSS:

```
.span {
    background-image: url("/F1/N1.png");
}
```

Comment: The code in question compiles perfectly fine for me and produces the expected CSS. When it comes to Less mixins, `;` and `,` are both valid mixin parameter separators and so there is not much difference between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `;` between params use `,` and it must work

```
.pic_url(@folder, @name) {
    background-image: url("/@{folder}/@{name}.png");
}
```

Comment: glad to be of help!